# jquery click event -

Tags: jquery, click, href

I want to perform an action when a user clicks on a div. However if he clicks on link within div, I want to send him directly to link. Now the href is being ignored.

```
<div id=myDiv>

   some text
   <a href="link1">my link</a>

   some text
   <a href="link2">my link</a>

   some text
   <a href="link3">my link</a>
<div>


$('.myDiv').live('click', function() {          
        console.log($(this));
        // if clicked on link, the go directly to the link
        ....
        // if clicked elsewhere on div, then perform another another action and return false
        return false;

    });
```

====== MY SOLUTION ====

I liked Rob's solution but the syntax was a bit vexing, so RTFM and came up with something similar that works  for me.

```
$('.myDiv').live('click', function(event) {         
   var $target = $(event.target);
   if( $target.is("a") ) {
    return true;
    }
    else{
      // do something else
      return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: What happens if you `return true;`?

Comment: This works...performs the href after doing other stuff, but would prefer to go directly to link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `event.target` property. The code below does not execute `return false` when an anchor is clicked.

```
$('.myDiv').live('click', function(event) {
    ....
    // `return false` only if element != <a>
    if(!$.nodeName(event.target, "a")) return false;

});
```

Comment: Doesn't he want `if($.nodeName(e.target, "a")) return true;` where the `....` is?

Comment: @Hogan He wants to follow the link. `return false` prevents the link from being followed. I have modified his code so that `return false` will not occur when the current target is an anchor, which has the same effect as `return true`.

Comment: So the default is to return true?  I did not see that in your code.

Comment: `$.nodeName` checks whether the given element (`event.target` = currently clicked element) is an `<a>` element (`"a"`). The `!` before the statement negates the expression. So, if the current element is not an `<a>` element, the function `returns false`, effectively blocking `click` events. When a link is clicked, the function works. @Hogan Inside a click event handler `return true` is equivalent to just `return`.

Comment: sorry I meant my code was ambiguous fragment. Yours was just vexing.

Answer (score 1):

Call `stopPropagation()` when the links are clicked:

```
$('.myDiv').live('click', function(e) {
    // Perform your action here
});

$('.myDiv a').live('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Isn't this the reverse of what he wants -- this stops a link from working, he wants the link to work.

Comment: @Hogan: Nope - `stopPropagation()` isn't `preventDefault()`. http://jsfiddle.net/8sfdQ/ (Hehe... the example doesn't work because of the cross-origin rule for iframes. Oops :P If you go to /show/ it does.)